# How to do scatterplot Visualization of Text Classification

Tags: classification, text-mining, visualization, multiclass-classification

I am working on my first ever ds problem on classification. I have got end to end process but not much visualization except bar charts and pie charts.

I want to see how well classes are distinguished in sample dataset itself to find anomaly in sample data or to see how many outliers sample have.

I see many nice scatterplot clustering done in many articles, pappers and books which are mostly based on numerical features. Something like following taken from scikit learn : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_random_dataset.html

[image]

However, most of those are for numeric features. How can I draw similar plot for textual features?

One way I can do it is converting all features into vectors; plot all the indexes(token indexes) on x-axis and their respective metric (TF or TF-IDF) on y-axis? But then there are so many features!?

Also, how can I analyze raw sample data in such clustering format without transforming them into vectors. I can do tokenization and some basic normalization.

For example  my sample data is 
text, category

```
"chiense restarant near me", chinesefoodlover
"japanese food near me", japanesefoodlover
```

I can break it down to

```
[chiense, restarant, near, me], chinesefoodlover
[japanese, food, near, me], japanesefoodlover
```

But then how to draw clusters of classes from there.

Comment: You can also visualize the [confusion matrix](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py). You are looking for a diagonal matrix, ideally.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at **t-SNE** for visualising high dimensional datasets such as words : http://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/